# I need to draw a coil. I am wrapping garland around two types of things. Columns & Poles.

Tags: calculus

I need to draw a coil. I am wrapping garland around two types of things. Columns & Poles. I need to know how much garland I will need for the following.

1) The garland is 12" in diameter
2) The Column is 15' tall & 12" Diameter
3) One Pole is 18' tall & 6" Diameter.
4) One Pole is 12' Tall & 6" Diameter.
5) The spacing is 12" between "wraps".

How do I figure out how much Green Christmas Garland I need to wrap around these

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ is the diameter and $s$ is the spacing between "wraps", then the length of one wrap is given by Pythagoras' theorem:
$$
l=\sqrt{(\pi d)^2+s^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Total length required is:

$$ =n \sqrt{(\pi d)^2+p^2}$$

found by development of   cylinder  diameter $d$, pitch $p$ or spacing between full turns/wraps,$n$ is number of turns.